# side by side installation fuerte and groovy

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1. I am curious if I can install ROS fuerte and groovy side by side?
2. Are there any configuration files etc. that risk being overwritten and causing problems?
3. Should I be aware of anything specific prior to using two different installs together?
4. Or is it fine to run the setup scripts in the shell depending on which one you wish to run and start using that version?

Thanks. -- Joe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51713/side-by-side-installation-fuerte-and-groovy/) by [scheme_bad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3922/scheme_bad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No problem for that under Ubuntu, they install to /opt/ros/fuerte and /opt/ros/groovy respectively, on purpose.

With two distros, it is usually safest to not source any setup.sh in your .bashrc, but to source the respective setup.sh per terminal, and not switch during that session. generally switching can work, but there can be undesired side-effects.

Also for writing your custom code, it is also safer to have separate source files (workspaces), unless you know well what you are doing.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6